# Set Order By Clause Dynamically for Procedure based data block

Tags: forms, oracle, plsql, oracleforms

Is it possible to set order by clause dynamically for procedure based data block?

I have tried adding a button and in When_Button_Pressed trigger I have used the below but did not work...

```
Set_Block_Property('XXFDF_DTL', Default_Where,v_where); 
Set_Block_Property('XXFDF_DTL',Order_By,'PAPERSTOCK');
```

Any inputs will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You will have to add a parameter to your procedure to designate the ordering you would like, and have the procedure do the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have a static sql and sort based on the value of the variable:

```
 select ... from ...
 order by decode(:val, 1, col1, 2, col2)
```